# How to remove all user created variables that start with a specific set of strings

Tags: r, variables

I've got ~20+ tmp. variables within a script, and was looking for a quicker way to remove all of them vs. typing of them out i.e rm(tmp.*), vs. rm(tmp.data.excel), rm(tmp.data.word), rm(tmp.data.FormulaOne), etc...

Comment: How did you wind up with all those tmp variables in the first place? Those probably shouldn't be polluting your global environment.

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: it would be easier to suggest something if we could see the code that created them. That might make it more clear why they were created. If there are just a bunch of steps you are performing to some data input, then you might do that within the context of an importing function with limited scope or maybe pipe data from one function to the next.

Comment: #Find all the locations which contain Long in the Description
tmp.long<-mutate(data.Excel.DF,linenumber = row_number()) %>% subset(Amount<0) %>% unnest_tokens(word, Description) %>% subset(word == "long") %>% .$linenumber

data.Excel.DF[tmp.long[!duplicated( tmp.long)],]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this using a regular expression via `ls`:

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^tmp"))
```